# Python dictionary Loop Help needed

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

```
cisco_ios_gig25_uplink = []



userName = 'admin'

passWord = 'cisco'

cisco_devices = {
'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
'username': userName,
'password': passWord,
'host': '',
}

dev1 = {'host': 'USSXXXX110A'}
dev2 = {'host': 'USSXXXX310A'}
dev3 = {'host': 'USSXXXX203C'}
dev4 = {'host': 'USSXXXX209B'}


for dev in cisco_devices.items():
    cisco_devices.update(dev1)
    cisco_ios_gig25_uplink.append(dict(cisco_devices))
    cisco_devices.update(dev2)
    cisco_ios_gig25_uplink.append(dict(cisco_devices))
    cisco_devices.update(dev3)
    cisco_ios_gig25_uplink.append(dict(cisco_devices))
    cisco_devices.update(dev4)
    cisco_ios_gig25_uplink.append(dict(cisco_devices))
```

When I run this for loop, I get the following result:

```
[{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX110A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX310A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX203C'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX209B'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX110A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX310A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX203C'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX209B'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX110A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX310A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX203C'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX209B'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX110A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX310A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX203C'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX209B'}]
```

So my question is : Why does python loop over it 4 times ?
I only want it to show up like the following - so how do I do that?

```
[{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX110A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX310A'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX203C'}, 
{'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'admin', 'password': 'cisco', 'host': 'USSXXXX209B'}]
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't loop over `dev1`, `dev2`, `dev3`, `dev4`. It loops over the dictionary entries inside of `cisco_devices`.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over cisco_devices. If you want to iterate over the different devs you have, place them in an array and loop over them.

Try instead this:

```
cisco_ios_gig25_uplink = []



userName = 'admin'

passWord = 'cisco'

cisco_devices = {
'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
'username': userName,
'password': passWord,
'host': '',
}

dev1 = {'host': 'USSXXXX110A'}
dev2 = {'host': 'USSXXXX310A'}
dev3 = {'host': 'USSXXXX203C'}
dev4 = {'host': 'USSXXXX209B'}


for dev in [dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4]:
    cisco_devices.update(dev)
    cisco_ios_gig25_uplink.append(dict(cisco_devices))

print(cisco_ios_gig25_uplink)
```